# Calling a function in abc.aspx.vb using jquery on keypress event of a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have defined a function sendDetails() in abc.aspx.vb. I want to use textbox keypress event and call this function. For this I'm trying to use jQuery as the textbox does not support keypress event. I tried a lot searching but not able to find a solution. Hoping to find one here.

abc.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="200" onkeypress="EnterEvent(event)">
```

abc.aspx.vb

```
Public Sub sendDetails()

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.txtTextBox.Text) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Me.txtTextBox.Text = ""


End Sub
```

Can anybody help me out with this? I need to write a jQuery.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, See http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can write a jQuery Ajax call on keypress event to achieve this. Remember that the function on the code behind side has to be static with "WebMethod" tag defined above it, to get it accessible via jQuery Ajax call. Here is a very basic example for keypress event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#txtTextBox").keypress(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/sendDetails",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: "{ TextBoxData:'" + $("#txtTextBox").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        //-- do whatever you need on returned result here
                        alert(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('Error: ' + result.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTextBox" runat="server" Width="100%" MaxLength="200"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

on the code behind side, define the shared/static function to be called as:

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function sendDetails(TextBoxData As String) As String
    'If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.txtTextBox.Text) Then
    '    Exit Sub
    'End If
    'Me.txtTextBox.Text = ""
    Return "Value in textbox is: " & TextBoxData
End Function
```

Remember that, since it is shared/static, you won't be able to access any page controls or viewstate.